# Hiding button until picture is selected

Tags: ios, uibutton, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I have an application that allows the user to select a picture from the camera roll, or take a new one, this then replaces a place holder image.

I want to create a button that when tapped clears the image (as it stands right now once you take a picture or select one from the library you can only replace it, but you can't remove it altogether)

I want the remove picture button to only show if a picture has been taken or chosen. I know this is possible having seen some other Apple apps do this but I don't know how to do it, and I've searched google and stackoverflow for a solution and haven't found anything that fits this description.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you need to implement the UIImagePickerControllerDelegate's [imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:) method. That method is called when the UIImagePickerController is done selecting a media. Very roughly something like this:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    // Dismiss the uiimagepicker
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    // Get the image that is selected  
    UIImage *imageSelected = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

    // Set the image to the place holder
    [self.placeholder setImage:imageSelected];

    // Hide the button
    self.imageSelectButton.hidden = YES;
}
```

Be sure to check out the other delegate methods to handle cancel events and such.

Comment: Note that in the example I am assuming you named your placeholder UIImage as `self.placeholder` and the button you want to hide as `self.imageSelectButton`. Replace those with the actual names.